# Make Excel insert day and date in a set format on a single click?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Just a quick one -

is there a way I can have a cell set as a clickable area or have something somewhere that'll when activated, set the cell to show the current day / month / year?

So:

Monday 26th December 2016

I have to update this manually every day in a large spreadsheet and it kills my will to live. It's one merged cell, but for ease I can split the cells if need be to have different formulas or whatever it needs.

Ta!

Cal

Comment: Is it it the same cell every day?

Comment: Just entering `=TEXT(NOW(),"dddd dd mmmm yyyy")` in that cell should bring you fairly close. Except the "th", not sure what to do about that.
Then in the "formulas" tab, select "Calculate now" to recalculate all the  functions.

Comment: Hi Steven, yep, sure is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, try using something along the lines of this for the cell containing the date:

```
=TEXT(TODAY(),"dddd ")&DAY(TODAY())&LOOKUP(DAY(TODAY()),{1,2,3,4,21,22,23,24,31;"st","nd","rd","th","st","nd","rd","th","st"})&TEXT(TODAY()," mmmm yyy")
```

To recalculate the value, there are a few options.
But with the usual settings excel will recalculate any time you change something in the sheet.
To force a change, you can however:

Either go to the *Formulas* tab ans select *calculate now*,
or have a macro update the formulas all the time, with something like:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Calculate
End Sub
```

In the sheet code. But this may be a bit overkill.

Comment: Ah, perfectly perfect. That'll do for me!

I also have dates that need to be set for the following weekend. Is there a way to make it update to the next weekend in line for the same idea? So it'd give me the coming Saturday in one, and the coming Sunday in the other?

Comment: @TprHCR I'm in a hurry, but check out this: https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-edate-function

Comment: @ChristoferWeber Awesome formula. @TprHCR I would not implement the `Worksheet_SelectionChange`, it's an overkill. The `TODAY()` function is volatile by nature, so it will recalculate on each change in sheet. You could also put the `TODAY()` into one cell, and then use result 4-times in Chris formula to avoid unnecessary multiple recalculation of one formula.